# String replace on Angular JS output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I replace a string in angular js?

This is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-attr-id="filter_id(event.kibana._source._id)"></tr>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filter_id = function(id){
    return id.replace(":","-");
}
```

But the id won't fill..

Comment: what do you mean "id won't fill"? Or can you give an example of id you try to pass to the function?

Comment: I mean the id remains empty in the DOM.

Comment: One variable cloud be event.kibana._source._id = "test:test:test", but I want it to be "test-test-test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you forgot to add the double-braces `{{}}` around the call:

```
<tr ng-attr-id="{{filter_id(event.kibana._source._id)}}"></tr>
```

Here's a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4ddEOHeLarYwpeER5mW?p=preview) showing it works. Also note that I changed your filter_id function to use regex for the string replace. As it stands your function would only replace the first occurrence of a `:`.